# How to analyze skewed and unskewed data on SPSS?

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, data-transformation, skewness

**Study design:**
I have shown participants a series of photos of themselves vs. other people's bodies (original and manipulated), and asked them to find the original. Their responses were recorded and they filled out body image questionnaires.

**IV:**
 - Body Image Anxiety (questionnaire scores)
 - Self vs. Other body stimuli

**DV:**
 - Error Rate (magnitude of error from 0 to 1)

- Participants were shown a series of photos one at a time, and pressed space bar when they think they see the original photo. 10 manipulated photos (5 fatter and 5 skinnier manipulations) and the original were shown in each trial. The photos manipulated the most were coded as 1 and 11, and the original photo was coded as 6.
- Error rate = |actual - entered|/actual -> so if a participant chose photo 5 (a manipulation), the error rate would be |5-6|/6 = .1667
- Error rates were separated into 1) error rate of seeing own photos; 2) error rate of other people's photos; 3) combined error rate from averaging the self and other error rates

**Problem:**
I was about to use repeated-measure ANOVA to analyze the data, but found that the error rate for self failed the normal distribution assumption (it's positively skewed). I was taught in lectures that I should only use repeated-measure ANOVA given the distribution was normal.

Should I transform the self error rate using the log10 function and analyze it as such? If not, how should I go about analyzing the data?

Comment: This is hard to follow. Can you say more about your situation, your data, your variables & your goals here? I'm not sure this can be answered at present.

Comment: Concluding that you cannot use ANOVA, solely based on the skewnesses of the variables, appears to have little or no basis. Instead of ruling out such a promising and powerful tool, one way to proceed is to conduct the ANOVA and follow it with diagnostics for assessing whether the underlying assumptions are plausible. In the absence of more information about the data and your objectives, though, it's going to be impossible to provide anything but such general advice.

Comment: This is considerably clearer--I think you're almost there. Can you explain how the error rates were calculated? Was a picture shown, & the participant guessed if it was a picture of themself or someone else, & the error was 0 if they got it right & 1 if they didn't?

Comment: Thanks for making a serious attempt to improve the question. Reading it now I had the same question as gung -- how was the error rate calculated? Down at the level of an individual participant looking at a single picture is it either "error" or "no error"? or even at that level is it a number in between 0 and 1? or is it something else?

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism. I incorporated more information on error rate calculation into the body of the question. All your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're calling an error rate appears to be some kind of score of how bad an error was made (low value means they were closer to the correct choice than a high value). Did I understand correctly?  When you "combine" what are you doing -- adding? Averaging?

Comment: Glen_b, yes, that is correct. Combine error rate is the average of self and other error rates.